# Fire macro in Personal.xlsb on ANY workbook open

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to place a macro in Personal.xlsb that will fire whenever any workbook is opened.  I have searched multple sites for an answer and all relate to Auto_Open or WorkBook_Open which have to be in a macro running in the workbook being opened.  Is there a way to see these events from another workbook?

Comment: This question has been asked before in SO :)

Comment: Also have a look here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx